# Ask Ubuntu does not display well on Microsoft Zune HD

Tags: support

I am the proud owner of an internet-enabled Microsoft Zune HD. However, I am frustrated by the limitations that occur when viewing the Ask Ubuntu site on my Zune HD. To start, the regular Ask Ubuntu site (not mobile) displays quite well for the most part, with the occasional layout glitch that comes with browsing the internet on a mobile device. The one problem is that when asking a question, you can not select tags to assign to your question, which results in an error when trying to post the question. Other than that, the full site works just fine. The mobile site, however, has severe layout flaws on the Zune HD screen. The questions on the main page are seemingly randomly placed on the page, covering each other and being an awful mess in general. The mobile site also has many more layout problems compared to the full site. I just wanted to make these bugs known to the rest of the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider giving [Stack Mobile](http://stackmobile.com) a try. It's a read-only front-end to the entire Stack Exchange network of sites that I wrote.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Does read only mean you can't edit tags or questions/answers? Can you ask questions or comment?

Comment: @William: Unfortunately yes - it means you cannot do anything that modifies / creates content on the site.

Comment: Well, its still good just for reading. I think I'll go over to the programmers stack excahnge and see if anyone with XNA experience would be willing to create an app for the zune.

Comment: @William: Well - keep in mind that nobody can create an app that posts questions / answers yet because the API only offers read-only access.

Comment: Yes, that is an issue. Still, even a viewer would be great. The Zune' s internet browser is IE6, so its very slow and incompatible with a lot of things.

Comment: @William: There's an [older version of StackMobile](http://stackmobile.com/old_version/) that's designed for older browsers. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, tht renders faster.